# -[UIViewController _keyboard]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b731ac0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikeyboard

I am writing an app with 3 viewControllers contained inside of a MainViewController. One of these is controlled through the storyboard and shows ads. The other two viewControllers are displaying information. Depending on the menu button pressed and the viewController to be presented the app determines which viewController to change.

So far everything is working well except when **ANY** textField is selected. This causes the error to display. The instance is the viewController containing the textField, and is also the UIViewController named in the error. Also, the instance is not nil. I've placed a breakpoint at: `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`

and this method is called before the crash happens. The app is universal and doesn't crash on the iPhone version, which uses the same setup except it only has the ads and another viewController displayed. Let me know if you need to see more code or have any ideas. I can't find the selector `_keyboard` anywhere and have no idea what to do from here.

I've tried to create a new project with minimal code to show the error, but new projects all work fine, so the problem isn't having too many viewControllers visible at once. I also know my transitioning code works fine because it works in the new projects. The viewControllers I've written are also not the problem, because the exact same viewController is used in the iPhone part of the app as well as in a new iPad only test project and the problem doesn't show up on them at all.

[edit - removed code, I tested the code in a new project and it worked fine]

[edit2 - added code and explanation]

```
@implementation FSMainiPadViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.leftView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.rightView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    
    if (!self.testVC) {
        self.testVC = [[FSTestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    }
    self.inputViewController = self.testVC;
    
    self.resultsVC = [[FSResultsTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.dataViewController = self.resultsVC;
    
    
    self.leftView.frame = CGRectMake(0, VIEWFRAMEOFFSET/2, self.view.frame.size.width/2 , self.view.frame.size.height - IPADBANNERHEIGHT - VIEWFRAMEOFFSET/2 - MENUHEIGHT);
    self.rightView.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width)/2, VIEWFRAMEOFFSET/2, self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height - IPADBANNERHEIGHT - VIEWFRAMEOFFSET/2 - MENUHEIGHT);

    
    [self addChildViewController:self.inputViewController];
    [self addChildViewController:self.dataViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.inputViewController.view];
    [self.view addSubview:self.dataViewController.view];
    [self.dataViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.inputViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Selecting the textField causes this same error. I have literally commented out everything else in my MainViewController and it still causes this issue, but if I create a new project, even including my more complicated code and xib's, I can't recreate the crash.

Let me know if you want more code.

### Stacktrace

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FSSettingsViewController _keyboard]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7da1dbf0'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x0326d946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02ef6a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x032755c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x031be3e7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x031bdfae _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
        5   UIKit                               0x01e46d91 -[UIInputViewSet keyboard] + 52
        6   UIKit                               0x01b0807c -[UIKeyboardImpl setOrientation] + 94
        7   UIKit                               0x01b082c8 -[UIKeyboardImpl setFrame:] + 197
        8   UIKit                               0x01939084 UIViewCommonInitWithFrame + 1072
        9   UIKit                               0x01938bea -[UIView initWithFrame:] + 124
        10  UIKit                               0x01b02b62 -[UIKeyboardImpl initWithFrame:] + 107
        11  UIKit                               0x01b01c58 +[UIKeyboardImpl sharedInstance] + 158
        12  UIKit                               0x01e3bf4f -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 962
        13  UIKit                               0x01a845a5 -[UIResponder(UIResponderInputViewAdditions) reloadInputViews] + 316
        14  UIKit                               0x01a838ec -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 562
        15  UIKit                               0x0194a1c0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 114
        16  UIKit                               0x02115477 -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 51
        17  UIKit                               0x01d183ef -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 200
        18  UIKit                               0x01d1aa16 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:] + 2762
        19  UIKit                               0x01d0e287 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 327
        20  UIKit                               0x01d0cb04 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 561
        21  UIKit                               0x01d0eb4d -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 60
        22  UIKit                               0x01d124ca ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke661 + 57
        23  UIKit                               0x01d1238d _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 317
        24  UIKit                               0x01d06296 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 3720
        25  UIKit                               0x0191f26b -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1356
        26  UIKit                               0x019200cf -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 769
        27  UIKit                               0x018e5549 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
        28  UIKit                               0x018f537e _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20690
        29  UIKit                               0x018c9b19 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206
        30  CoreFoundation                      0x031911df __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
        31  CoreFoundation                      0x03186ced __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
        32  CoreFoundation                      0x03186248 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
        33  CoreFoundation                      0x03185bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
        34  CoreFoundation                      0x031859fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
        35  GraphicsServices                    0x0519f24f GSEventRunModal + 192
        36  GraphicsServices                    0x0519f08c GSEventRun + 104
        37  UIKit                               0x018cd8b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
        38  FoodStorage                         0x000a795d main + 141
        39  libdyld.dylib                       0x04e14ac9 start + 1
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This is the first time the Google machine has let me down. In all the problems I've had making this app, this is the only problem I can't seem to find anyone else having.

Comment: Have you tried turning on zombies in your build scheme to see if it points to a particular object?

Comment: Yes, zombies are turned on and it doesn't seem to make a difference. The instance being sent the _keyboard selector is still in memory when the app crashes, I also didn't seem to find any other zombie objects.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm going to assume this code works flawlessly when running on an iOS7 device and probably when compiled against the iOS7 SDK on an iOS8 device.

You appear to have had the misfortune of naming one of your properties the same thing as an Apple added property:

```
@interface UIResponder (UIResponderInputViewAdditions)
// Called and presented when object becomes first responder.  Goes up the responder     chain.
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIInputViewController *inputViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
@end
```

When the user taps on your text field, UIKit will grab your view controller thinking it's a `UIInputViewController` and send the private message [`_keyboard`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/a8f9f7eb4882c9dfc87166d876c547b75a24c5bb/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIInputViewController.h#L29).  Your view controller doesn't implement this method and it crashes the app.

The only thing you need to do here is rename your property from `inputViewController` to something else like `myInputViewController`.

Comment: Holy Awesome, I can't thank you enough. The funny thing is, while looking through my stack trace trying to figure out what the _keyboard selector was, I found the UIInputViewController, and I know that it is a bad idea to use apple defined names, but it didn't even click that I had named my container that. This has literally been a weeks worth of banging my head against the keyboard.

Comment: This also explains why the iPhone app doesn't crash, I don't use that particular container for the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your iPad storyboard. Check all the view controllers' connections. You might have a connection in the storyboard that doesn't get use, delete them. It has got to be there if it works on iPhone and not the iPad. Place breakpoints everywhere to see the last position before crash.

Comment: I couldn't find anything missing in my storyboard, so I deleted it and created a new one, still getting the error. I added the xml for my storyboard to see if maybe I'm just not seeing something that is important. The only IBoutlet in my code is the adView which is the containerView in my storyboard. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: In your project settings under general - deployment info, check your main interface. Or try running a new clean slate iPad storyboard. If this error occurred after you updated Xcode, try changing your deployment target.