# App crashed on touch of UITextField in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I added one text field in storyboard and link it with header file.

Now when I run the application I get the error like

```
[InputViewController _keyboard]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I tried many things but it didn't worked.

here is interface of text field

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *countryCode;
```

This is the line that uses the value of text field

```
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"country=%@", self.countryCode.text];
```

How can I solve this?

Connections of Textfield can be seen below:

[image]

Comment: try to check your UIViewController, maybe you connected something bad in your storyboard

Comment: What does stack trace say? (If you aren't getting stack trace in console, add exception breakpoint with `bt` as debugger command.)

Comment: Oh, and do you by any chance have a property named `inputViewController`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27975216/988769

Comment: I think the problem is in name `InputViewController`, Do you have any object named that?

Comment: Yes I have this line in my code '@property (strong, nonatomic) InputViewController *inputViewController;'  @NSNoob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your name:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) InputViewController *inputViewController;
```

Apple has added a property with similar name in UIResponder class:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIInputViewController *inputViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

This is what happens:

1. User taps your TextField.
2. Because of the similarly named property, UIKit Framework mistakes your custom InputViewController to be an instance of type `UIInputViewController`.
3. UIKit tries to call `keyboard` method of `UIInputViewController` on your InputViewController's instance.
4. `keyboard` method does not exist on your InputViewController because it is not an instance of `UIInputViewController`.
5. You get the error that an unrecognized selector is sent to your ViewController because there is no such method in your ViewController and the application correctly gets crashed.

Change the name of that property and you should be fine.

For more details, See [Brian Nickel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/860000/brian-nickel)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930743/uiviewcontroller-keyboard-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-0x7b731ac0?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Also Read, Apple's documentation on [UIInputViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIInputViewController_Class/).